# Vue.js: Error after configuring Router.js. Vue/types/umd. chokidar (C drive error)

Tags: vue.js

I was running a dev server after changing my router.js file. Adding a webpage .vue file to the configuration. After doing so it failed to compile with only one errors. This is the output:

```
This dependency was not found:
* vue/types/umd in ./src/router.js
To install it, you can run: npm install --save vue/types/umd
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\hiberfil.sys'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\swapfile.sys'
```

I tried the advice, and installed `vue/types/umd` and it still compiled with an error. I then uploaded my project to GitLab. Deleted the project on my Documents folder then downloaded it again. Used `npm install` then the typical `npm run serve` and still the same error.

Answer (score 8):

Check if by accident this kind of import didn't appear in your file ./src/router.js. I had this error when this line appeared in my file. Probably I pressed some key when wanted to use nextTick. In your case it could be attempt to import router. So when I removed this import line everything went back to normal.

```
import { nextTick } from 'vue/types/umd';
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what happened to me. It auto imported nextTick, which I had mistyped and erased, but the import was still there.

Answer (score 0):

npm install --save vue/types/umd

npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "vue/types/umd" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/lenovo/.npm/_logs/2022-05-16T17_40_02_280Z-debug.log

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31788349)